# How to properly implement "Confirm Password" in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

There's already an [answered question](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/01/CompareAttributeASPNETMVC3.aspx) about the same subject but as it's from '09 I consider it outdated.

How to properly implement "Confirm Password" in ASP.NET MVC 3?

I'm seeing a lot of options on the Web, most of them using the `CompareAttribute` in the model [like this one](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/01/CompareAttributeASPNETMVC3.aspx)

The problem is that definitely `ConfirmPassword` shound't be in the model as it shouldn't be persisted.

As the whole unobstrusive client validation from MVC 3 rely on the model and I don't feel like putting a ConfirmPassword property on my model, what should I do?

Should I inject a custom client validation function? If so.. How?

Comment: Not all the types (or type members) that are in *Model* must be persisted. What about your server validation?

Comment: Not only ConfirmPassword, but also Password should not be persisted. Darin Dimitrov's solution with a ViewModel is correct except for the note about AutoMapper. You should always salt and secure hash password prior to persisting it.

Comment: Darin never indicated that he would persist the plaintext password, he just said that he would map the viewmodel to a domain model, and pass that to a repository.  I would argue that the details of hashing a password more correctly belongs with the persistence code than in the presentation code (Why should my MVC controllers have to know the details of a secure hash?).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

> As the whole unobstrusive client validation from MVC 3 rely on the
>   model and I don't feel like putting a ConfirmPassword property on my
>   model, what should I do?

A completely agree with you. That's why you should use view models. Then on your view model (a class specifically designed for the requirements of the given view) you could use the `[Compare]` attribute:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password doesn't match, Type again !")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // TODO: Map the view model to a domain model and pass to a repository
    // Personally I use and like AutoMapper very much (http://automapper.codeplex.com)

    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Comment: I don't have a `Compare` attribute available... what am I missing?

Comment: @jocull, erm, ASP.NET MVC 3? If you are using an older version you won't have this attribute.

Comment: It's definitely MVC 3... am I missing an included assembly?

Comment: @jocull, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute.aspx). Assembly: `System.Web.Mvc.dll`. Namespace: `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: Oh crap, I forgot for this project that the "core" models are in a separate assembly... that is probably the problem. Thanks.

Comment: In newer C# its better use `[Compare(nameof(Password), ...]` instead of hardcoding `Password` property name.

Comment: Does that mean both Password and ConfirmPassword are being sent to the server? Do we really need both if the validation can be done client-side?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the default VS2010 template for a MVC3 app.

It contains a **RegisterModel** (a 'ViewModel') that contains the Password and ConfirmPassword properties. The validation is set  on the ConfirmPassword.

So the answer is that the Models in MVC don't have to be (usually aren't) the same as your business Models.