# Compare password using DataAnnotation in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a website using `asp.net mvc 4` & `EF6` where I've Password & Confirm Password fields. If both are same then data will be saved in MSSQL db as usual. I'm using `Compare` `DataAnnotation` to compare those two fields & I've added that code in `EF6` generated model class. But for some reason, my data is not saving in db. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UserReg(ClientReg regCl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ClientRegs.Add(regCl);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Register");
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public partial class ClientReg
{
    public int serial { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Compare("password")]
    public string ComparePass { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyProj.Models.ClientReg
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserReg", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="editor-label">
        <strong>Username</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <strong>Password</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <strong>Confirm Password</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.ComparePass)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.ComparePass)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
}
```

I can't find any errors in my code. Am I doing something wrong here? How can I compare two password fields by using DataAnnotation? Need this help badly! Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the table you trying to save data on?

Comment: Why on earth do you have a `ComparePass` field in your database? You need a Register view model with the `ComparePass` property and a separate data model without it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks. Can you provide a code for your explanation?

Comment: @Oluwafemi, here is the structure of the table :

`serial -> int -> auto increment, no null, PK` ;
`username -> varchar(20) -> no null` ;
`password -> varchar(50) -> no null`

Comment: @SinOscuras, Create a new MVC project in VS with forms authentication and look at the code associated with the `AccountController` and its models. The fact you appear to be storing passwords in the database in plain text is dreadful practice (and if this is a real app, you will need a good lawyer)

Answer (score 1):

You should separate data access class from view model. The view model should contain the DataAnnotations.Compare attribute.

```
/* View model */
public partial class ClientRegModel
{
    public int serial { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Compare("password")]
    public string ComparePass { get; set; }
}

/* Your DbContext or data class */
public partial class ClientReg
{
    public int serial { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

You can also checkout this post [How to properly implement "Confirm Password" in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801585/how-to-properly-implement-confirm-password-in-asp-net-mvc-3)